# CSRF token: receiving token from server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, csrf-protection

Recently I've made a CSRF protection in needed html forms on website.

This works as follows:

- Server generates hash and puts it in the session variable
- Then hash is inserted into html `input` inside the html form.
- When form is submitted, server takes session variable and compares it to `post` from client's form.

So that works fine, but when I need to use JavaScript to submit form and receive
response it doesn't works, because token is regenerated when client makes request with that form.

---

Is it safe to return new token with server response?

Or should I do it differently, like generating hash only one time per session?

Comment: I would suggest you to implement ,generating hash only one time per session.

Comment: @shrikant Yeah, exactly. I saw the similar question and response was that it's better to use per-session token because of being more comfortable.